# Newtonsoft JObject adding newline characters when converting to string

Tags: c#, json.net, tostring

I have a C# program that adds properties to a JObject but when I convert to string, it has \r and \n characters in the output.  I'm using a very simple example with only the name and value:

```
JObject jo = new JObject();
jo.Add("role", "user");
jo.ToString() //Output is:  "{\r\n  \"role\": \"user\"\r\n}"
```

However if I do the following:

```
jo["role"].ToString()  // output is: "user"
```

So, how do I stop it from adding the /r/n when converting to string?

Answer (score 1):

Just after I posted the question, I found this so I thought I'd post in case anyone else has the problem.

```
jo.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```